# Optionally prevent a string at the end of a wildcard from being matched

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
12345 This could be anythingREMOVE
```

I need to match `12345` and `This could be anything`.  Unfortunately, the format I need to parse also has a string at the end of the line that isn't always present (`REMOVE` in this example).  How can I match what I'm looking for without `REMOVE`?  I've tried the following pattern:

```
^(\d{5}) (.*)(?:REMOVE|$)
```

Unfortunately, `REMOVE` is picked up by the wildcard:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12345 This could be anythingREMOVE
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12345
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => This could be anythingREMOVE
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
^(\d{5})((?:.(?!REMOVE))+.)
```

**How It Works**

1. `^(\d{5})` -- Matches start of string, followed by five digits `[0-9]`. Group of parentheses use to captured the text matched.
2. `((?:.(?!REMOVE))+` -- Matches any character if not immediately followed by the secuence `REMOVE` one or more times. It stops at the `n` in `anything`. it ***can't*** match the `g` because is followed by `REMOVE`.
3. `.)` -- Allow the `g` to match.

Answer (score 2):

If last string `REMOVE` is optional then why can't use use htis regex:

```
"/^(\d{5}) /"
```

However if you really want to avoid `REMOVE` in matching pattern then use this:

```
$s = '12345 This could be anythingREMOVE';
if (preg_match("/^(\d{5}) (.*?)(?:REMOVE|)$/", $s, $arr))
   var_dump($arr);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(34) "12345 This could be anythingREMOVE"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "12345"
  [2]=>
  string(22) "This could be anything"
}
```

Comment: I need to match "This could be anything" as well.  Sometimes it has `REMOVE` on the end, sometimes it doesn't.  Either way, I'd like to not have `REMOVE` in the match.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava.  If I use your second line as-is, the `This could be anything` isn't matched.  If I modify it to `^(\d{5}) (.*)(?=(?:REMOVE)?)$`, index 2 still contains `This could be anythingREMOVE`.

Comment: Good to know, sorry I didn't realize you wanted to capture string between first number and `REMOVE`